# Got warning: warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

Tags: python, cvxpy

I try to use cvxpy by using this code

`# Number of variables
n = len(symbols)

## The variables vector

x = Variable(n)

## The minimum return

req_return = 0.02

## The return

ret = r.T*x

## The risk in xT.Q.x format

risk = quad_form(x, C)

## The core problem definition with the Problem class from CVXPY

prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0])`

And I got warning

````
C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py:593: UserWarning: 
This use of ``*`` has resulted in matrix multiplication.
Using ``*`` for matrix multiplication has been deprecated since CVXPY 1.1.
    Use ``*`` for matrix-scalar and vector-scalar multiplication.
    Use ``@`` for matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplication.
    Use ``multiply`` for elementwise multiplication.
This code path has been hit 2 times so far.

  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```
`




Try to solve the warning  and no idea about warning
````

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of replicable code to make this more readable, and hopefully answerable.

Also, you are using code formatting for the error message instead of using for the code, so you got that backwards.

Comment: You(?) wrote `r.T * x`, and the error is telling you that usage is deprecated. Use `r.T @ x`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Warning mean *your code run properly* so Let's see the warning

---

The Warning tell us that

```
Using ``*`` for matrix multiplication has been deprecated since CVXPY 1.1.
```

so you already use CVXPY version upper 1.1
How to solve:

```
    Use ``*`` for matrix-scalar and vector-scalar multiplication.
Use ``@`` for matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplication.
Use ``multiply`` for elementwise multiplication.
```

If `ret = r.T*x` cannot run you can try `ret = r.T @x` from [CVXPY DOC](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html)